# ATM Card Pin Validation -Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I working on a project using TKinter and Python to develop UI based ATM were user will enter the card pin number, pass the validation and moves to check screen, which works fine. Now i need to display the message as "Invalid PIN number 1 to 3" and after 3rd attempt, i need to display the message as "Multiple attempts, Your card is blocked, please contact customer service."

```
    def enter_pin():

        pinnum=self.txtRecipt.get("1.0","end-1c")
        if ((pinnum == str("0000")) or (pinnum == str("9874")) or (pinnum == str("5689") )):
            self.textRep.delete("1.0",END)
            self.textRep.insert(END, 'Welcome to MY ATM'  + "\n\n")
            self.textRecipt.insert(END, 'Withdraw Cash\n")
            self.textRecipt.insert(END, 'Print Receipt\n")
            self.textRecipt.insert(END, 'Balance\n")
            self.textRecipt.insert(END, 'Change Pin\n")
        else:
            self.txtRecipt.delete("1.0", END)
            self.txtRecipt.insert(END, 'Invalid Pin Number'+ "\n\n")
```

Now how to add below function in the code above so it will display on the text box of my ATM UI

```
def pin_num():
    attempt= 0
    while attempt < 3:
        num = input('Please Enter Your 4 Digit Pin: ')
        if enter_pin(pinnum):
            print("Pin accepted!")
        else:
            print("Invalid pin")
            attempt += 1
            print("Multiple attempts, Your card is blocked, please contact customer service")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are changing the text of the `Text` widgets every time you want to display some message. Displaying output in the same place you are taking input, is not a very right idea.

I would suggest, use a `Label` to display the messages, or also, you can use `messagebox` to display the message boxes in your application.

---

However, with your current code, what you can do is, create a global variable for `attempts` and edit the function `enter_pin` as per your logic:

```
def enter_pin():   
    message = textRep.get("1.0","end-1c")
    if message=="Welcome\nYou are authorized!\n":        #if user already entered the correct pin, no need to check further
        return

    global attempts                            #the number of attempts left
    attempts -=1
    if attempts<0:                             #when no attempts left
        txtRecipt.delete("1.0", END)
        txtRecipt.insert(END, "Multiple attempts, Your card is blocked, please contact customer service")
        return                                 #no need to check further
    
    pinnum  = txtRecipt.get("1.0","end-1c")
    if ((pinnum == str("0000")) or (pinnum == str("9874")) or (pinnum == str("5689") )):
        textRep.delete("1.0", END)
        textRep.insert(END, 'Welcome\nYou are authorized!\n')
        #....whatever messages you want to display
    elif attempts==0:                          #if it's wrong pin and also this was the last try
        enter_pin()                            #then call this function again, then it will go to the case- if attempts<0
    else:
        txtRecipt.delete("1.0", END)
        txtRecipt.insert(END, 'Invalid Pin Number'+ "\n\n")

attempts = 3        #initialize the variable it with value 
txtRecipt = Text(root, height=2)
txtRecipt.pack()
b= Button(root, text="ENTER", command=enter_pin, width = 5)
b.config(font=("Helvetica", 10, 'bold'))
b.pack(pady = 10)
textRep   = Text(root, height=2)
textRep.pack()
```